# Customize jQuery Plugin Help

Tags: jquery, plugins, customization

I need a little help getting [this jQuery plugin](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/) to work correctly for me.

I need the previous button to be disabled when it's on the first slide, and when it's on the last slide it needs to have a `submit` button.

I'm using this plugin for a fancy form. :)  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you don't mind editing the source code directly, you'll need to add callbacks to the animate functions.

There is this line in the code for "Left arrow click":

```
$('.panel-container', slider)
  .animate({ marginLeft: offset }, 
    settings.slideEaseDuration, 
    settings.slideEaseFunction);
```

Add one more argument at the end that is your callback.  There are also other similar animate() calls.  I'll leave it up to you to decide whether you want to make it a setting =)

Comment: This seems to be the best option.  Thanks!